# Magento 2 Change the block style of Luma theme?

Tags: magento2, css

I've seen solutions to extend and change the subject. I have created my own theme. I could change colors and some styles that are predefined in the file _theme.less

But I can not change other styles that does not come preset in that file.
Specifically I wanted to change the styles that apply to static blocks of the home page and/or category view pages.

I have located the style and I copied in _theme.less:

```
`.training-erin .content { width: 30%; top: 16px; bottom: 16px; right:` 16px; }
```

I have emptied the cache, the store is in development mode and is compiled on the browser side. But nothing.

Should we use other notations in _theme.less ?, it is necessary to modify the layout to incorporate a custom css sheet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try clearing server cache, as described here for example: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#css_debug_server

Comment: Thank you Alex. But the cache it´s disable, and I execute magento comand to clean and flush cache, but nothing

Answer (score 0):

you need to first override **_layout** file.

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\custom\web\css\source\_layout.less
```

you can write here your css as your requirement.